# Gziped Css and JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, gzip

I can't get my gziped css and js files to work. They are compressed but when I open the link to them I get something like this as result:

```
    ‹������Í½{Û6²0üÿ~
››#“,KNÛm©0ÞÄI¶=ÛÛi²·WVúP$%Ñ–DY_"i?û;\IÊv»çý=owc‘ 0�ƒÁ`03¸‰Å"ý=ž¬³ÈóÄ8^žOòä*K£a<Yfb™Å‹dü]ÍÖ“É†ëY²Ê‹ÙA2ôôÍ/—ÁFçƒ·Vžvó¡h€Sf¸Á§®UÙj±ÎvXH"]$0‰ž§2Åiúî&›­¾Ï—«l–- ŠšTÿh0Y/ŽÄ0ŸL¸¹‚útës§ƒI‚M:‹l™­Ü"‹lµ^Ì¨­¤¨¦¬Vq2&HÁæPÊ¡íQé³TÌÊ
„Î~Z—¿¶Iº1ºl£aÀpëâI¶�?þtðîïï~üxðúãÇ×çßþ�‡‡‡Gung†Ö´Ì6ÐÃ´HÖShKk”­ÞM2||sÿ]ê«Ôxy^°yjf=¶Ý2Åí¬¦XöŸÛóvÝ?ø
\óeë‡¢øX“e´¹ÉKøzÖOÖù$
½øE–¥_}sš¦_Ùþ²~Ýî|õu–œ&j
³oÚÁàOéàÀÆÎ"ººŸg?
#
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how I should resolve this?

Apache modules like deflate,expires,headers are all installed and working.

The platform I'm using is typo3.

Thanks.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="typo3temp/scriptmerger/compressed/head-ed0db5492e25e2aae2d5194f2417f7f4.merged.gz.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="typo3temp/scriptmerger/compressed/head-51cb0e8880d742a31d3b7277d848f046.merged.gz.css" />

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="typo3temp/scriptmerger/compressed/head-fd881451a9d72dbe96f8afc7214bf265.merged.gz.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post the headers of the response

Comment: Your response headers must be wrong.  Or, you are double-compressing your data.

Comment: what browser are you using that is showing you the compressed data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information. Deflate module can't uncompress gzip files. You need also to add css and js files to gzip handler in apache configuration otherwise the files doesn't get uncompressed. It's not true about double compression because the normal compression is a transparent process. I wouldn't use Typo3 backend compression anyway. I also have big problems with it. If you want more speed use an alternative webserver like nginx or lighttpd.

Answer (score -1):

As Brad already pointed out, it looks like you're double gzipping your data. Usually when you use server/browser gzip, you just write your files as normal uncompressed text. It's the server software's (Apache) job to gzip the data on the fly and send it to the browser, which then transparently un-gzips the data.

If you want, you can upload pre-gzipped files to the server, but you need to then do additional configuration (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html). However I don't know much about this as I don't use it; the CPU time required to do it on the fly is insignificant.

Comment: Typo3 can use a special be-compression and can merge and zip css and js files but you need a new type handler and htaccess rules. This isn't really a proper solution.

Comment: The type handler and rules is what I was referring to in my mention of content negotiation, to serve the gz files to the browser with the broswer decompressing them.